# WebView not loading the file from internal storage

Tags: android, android-webview, android-download-manager

I am trying to download HTML files from server then load it in webview. The files are being downloaded but they are not loading in the webview. Webview says `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` even after restarting the app when the download completes.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    webView.loadUrl("file://"+Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+File.separator+"test.html");
    Log.e("CHECKKK", String.valueOf(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+File.separator+"test.html"));

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                myDownload("http://xxxxxx.com/xxxx/test.html");
                myDownload("http://xxxxxx.com/xxxx/mypic1.jpg");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage() + "\n" + e.getCause(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void myDownload(String myURL) {

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(myURL));
    request.setTitle("File Download");
    request.setDescription("Downloading....");
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    String nameOfFile = URLUtil.guessFileName(myURL, null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(myURL));
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this,Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, nameOfFile);

    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);
}
```

Comment: You requested read external storage permission in manifest file?

Comment: 'WebView not loading the file from internal storage'. Please change that in 'WebView not loading the file from external storage'.

Comment: `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+File.separator+"test.htm`. Please log that and look what it is.

Comment: @greenapps Yes Permission is requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `webView.loadUrl()` should work but I think you are missing a slash in your filepath string. You could try `"file:///"+Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+File.separator+"test.html"`

Notice the extra slash in `file:///`

You may also not be accessing the downloads folder correctly. Try doing it this way instead:

```
File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File htmlFile = new File(file.getAbsolutePath()+"/test.html");
webView.loadUrl(htmlFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

**UPDATE**

It seems a mix of some of these methods was required. The correct format was:
`webView.loadUrl("file://"+htmlFile.getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: Just a guess since most other examples I've seen do it that way. Another issue may be the way the downloads folder is being accessed. I've added some code above which shows another way of doing that which may solve the issue.

Comment: Yes. This looks better. This is the normal way to determine the download directory. But now you omitted file://. `webView.loadUrl("file://"+htmlFile.getAbsolutePath());`.

Comment: @greenapps `webView.loadUrl("file://"+htmlFile.getAbsolutePath());` worked! :) Thanks

Comment: @akkk - I added your final solution to my answer above. Feel free to add your own answer or accept this one. Up to you.

Comment: @greenapps Thanks for your input. You are more than welcome to create your own answer to have it accepted. But I do feel my answer was helpful.

Comment: `Notice the extra slash in file:///`. Well that was not very helpfull i think. And you should not have made that `UPDATE` of course as it was not your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file into a `String` and then use

```
// read from file
String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```

Comment: in my case html file is being downloaded from server. So how do i convert that html file to String form?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-do-i-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file